# AWS CloudFormation export yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, export, aws-cloudformation, config

Basically I've created an AWS project using yaml file and after that, I've made many changes in the graphic interface. Now I would like to duplicate this project, but my yaml file is outdated. Is there a way for me to somehow export these changes into the yaml file or I have to manualy write all the changes into it?

Comment: Sorry, this project is kind of on hault right now, as soon as I will be able to respond to you I will.

Comment: Hello, we have succesfully created the file, thank you for your response, it was very helpful! Maybe one thing, it exported everything including some personal user informations, is there a way to exclude this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [drift detection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/detect-drift-stack.html) in CloudFormation which you can use to detect differences between current stack and the resources.

There is also an external tool called [former2](https://former2.com/), but this is to generate entire templates based on existing infrastructure, which can also be helpful in updating your own templates to match your resources.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and then accept your answer if everything works.

Comment: @Deesak No problem. Let me know how it will go.